# P0136 Bank 1 Sensor 2 - Sensor location

Tags: toyota, sensor, o2-sensor, p0136

I'm getting P0136 bank 1 sensor 2 circuit malfunction from my Toyota Camry 4 cylinder, which from past experience means I need to replace it.  I've replaced the O2 sensor in the exhaust manifold before.  However, is sensor 2 the sensor in the exhaust manifold, or is it the one underneath the car?

Answer (score 4):

Bank 1 Sensor 2 should be the sensor downstream of the catalytic converter.  Bank 1 Sensor 1 would be upstream of the catalytic converter.  With a 4 cylinder, everything should be Bank 1 (No Bank 2).

So, Bank 1 Sensor 2 should be the one under the car.  The one on/at the exhaust manifold should be Bank 1 Sensor 1.

You might eyeball the wiring and / or check it with a multimeter, it's possible you've just got a broken wire or a bad ground.  Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYMGnvtgi8w).  You can also use a scan tool and see what the powertrain controller is seeing on a vehicle with [OBDII.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#OBD-II)

Answer (score 1):

After the catalytic converter. [image]

Look up multiple pictures on [Bank 1 Sensor 2 on YOUCANIC.](https://www.youcanic.com/article/o2-bank-1-sensor-2-sensor)